# Hide element inside Iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying to hide element inside Iframe from different website.
This is the embed code for Iframe

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=NtQzb5gDVTp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="vr"></iframe>
```

I want to hide the top bar at the top.
I'm trying to use this css:

```
#model-title .title-row {
    height: 50px;
}
```

I tried from my browser developer mode and it works.
My question is: How I can Include this css code in my page to hide this element and make it savable

Comment: The iframe has nothing to do with the parents CSS. You would have to inject stuff into that page directly. If it is from a different domain, there is nothing you can do. So is the page in the same domain?

Comment: Oh no :( the page not from my website, Can I use other tricky way like jquery or something to do this? or run css code after my page is rendered or something?

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: *"So is the page in the same domain?"*

Comment: @epascarello Not from my website, on other domain

Comment: So there is nothing you can do. Same Origin Policy prevents you from messing with another domain. Imagine someone loading up a bank or gmail into an iframe and altering it.